# Copy a database schema into another database in SQL Server using VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Using SQL Server 2014.

I want to copy a database (say d1) schema (without data) to another database (say d2) using vb.net.

Such that on a click of a button, the database is created/copied.

Searched many things, but not helpful.

Searched Microsoft TechNet Library, followed every step from the link but something not working...

[How to: Transfer Schema and Data from One Database to Another in Visual Basic .NET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162138(v=sql.90).aspx)

Database is been copied but tables/procedures/views nothing inside.

Answer (score 0):

Missing type means you have **not** added all possible references. You even mention further below in your post that a dll is not available anywhere, so how can you have added all possible references?

So, searching for "smoenum.dll" on google, finds this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/252adaa4-fc12-436d-91df-a2e8a98c7f2f/sql-2008-missing-microsoftsqlserversmoenumdll?forum=sqltools , which mentions that the the file has been renamed in later versions of SQL Server:

> "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll is available in SQL Server 2005 and
>   is removed from SQL Server 2008. If you have a SQL Server 2005
>   installed in any machine, it would be under C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies folder But the dll wont be available in
>   the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies
>   directory."

Instead you should use:

> "Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
>
> Above dlls are newly added in SQL Server 2008 which might be useful
>   for your case.
>
> The other dlls useful for your case in both versions are
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll"

Comment: Well, I try your way, but 1 thing is still a problem is that 90 folder has no SDK and further directories/folders.
There are just 2 folders in 90, i.e 'License Terms' and 'Shared'
So I searched other folders and found SDK/Assemblies in 100,110,120,130 directories and took assemblies from 100. I am understanding all this stuff for the first time, I wish I understand thoroughly and help others like you helped me.. I reply about this after adding the references mentioned by you. Thanx

Comment: Well, I added all the following references, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll , Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll , Microsoft.SqlServer.Connectioninfo.dll , Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll , Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll but still the same error..

Database type expected.

Is there any Namespace I need to add, I added "Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo", "Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common" and others such as windows.forms and data.sqlclient..